# SQL Server - Can't change datetime to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have this sql which has some date format issue, problem is that I can freely change **EndDate** to whatever I want, but for **StartDate** I can't seem to change it one bit, it always have this timestamp that I am trying to get rid of.

Basically whatever I do in varchar, date or any format I just can't change it and remove hours minutes and seconds from it.

So I am guessing it is a problem in this else, maybe those two selects aren't meant to be coupled like this, causing the problem

```
CASE 
        when p.pname in ('Compz') 
        THEN ji.MADE
        else
        (select min(CONVERT(date, MADE)) from changegroup cg1 inner join changeitem ci1 on ci1.groupid = cg1.id
             where ji.id = cg1.issueid and CONVERT(nvarchar, ci1.NSTRING) in ('Here','There')) end as StartDate,
    (select max(CONVERT(date, MADE)) from changegroup cg1 inner join changeitem ci1 on ci1.groupid = cg1.id
             where ji.id = cg1.issueid and CONVERT(nvarchar, ci1.NSTRING) in ('1','2','3', '4')) as EndDate,
             re.pname as resolution
FROM project p

StartDate: 2018-02-22 00:00:00
EndDate: 2018-07-05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue here is, You're converting the Subquery result to Date, however the return of the first column in your `case` (`ji.MADE`) is still `datetime`. So by default, SQL Server will cast the other result sets also to `DATETIME`.

there are 2 approaches you can use here, the first one is to cast `ji.MADE` also as `DATE`

```
CASE 
    when p.pname in ('Compz') 
        THEN CONVERT(DATE,ji.MADE)-- Like This
    else
        (select min(CONVERT(date, MADE)) from changegroup cg1 inner join changeitem ci1 on ci1.groupid = cg1.id
             where ji.id = cg1.issueid and CONVERT(nvarchar, ci1.NSTRING) in ('Here','There')) end as StartDate,
    (select max(CONVERT(date, MADE)) from changegroup cg1 inner join changeitem ci1 on ci1.groupid = cg1.id
             where ji.id = cg1.issueid and CONVERT(nvarchar, ci1.NSTRING) in ('1','2','3', '4')) as EndDate,
             re.pname as resolution
FROM project p
```

or put a cast all over the `CASE` and convert it as `DATE`

```
CONVERT(DATE,
CASE 
    when p.pname in ('Compz') 
        THEN ji.MADE
    else
        (select min(CONVERT(date, MADE)) from changegroup cg1 inner join changeitem ci1 on ci1.groupid = cg1.id
             where ji.id = cg1.issueid and CONVERT(nvarchar, ci1.NSTRING) in ('Here','There')) end) as StartDate,
    (select max(CONVERT(date, MADE)) from changegroup cg1 inner join changeitem ci1 on ci1.groupid = cg1.id
             where ji.id = cg1.issueid and CONVERT(nvarchar, ci1.NSTRING) in ('1','2','3', '4')) as EndDate,
             re.pname as resolution
FROM project p
```